# Centering a CSS3 shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to center an anchor tag which is displayed as a CSS3 shape (a large "play"-arrow) in a div.

My markup is as follows:

```
<div class="element halfcol">
    <div class="inner beige-bg fullheight">
        <div class="element-content">                       
            <a href="#" class="play-button"></a>                            
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.element {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
.element .inner {
   border: 2px solid #94111e;
   min-height: 50px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #fcf9e3;
   height: inherit;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #646464;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #646464;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #646464;
}
.element .inner .element-content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: inherit;
}
.element .inner .no-padding {
  padding: 0px;
}
.element .beige-bg {
  background-color: #fcf9e3;
}
.element .red-bg {
  background-color: #94111e;
}
.element .transparent-bg {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.element .white-bg {
   background-color: #ffffff;
 }
 .element .smallheight,
 .element .doubleheight,
 .element .fullheight {
    overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 .element .smallheight {
    height: 90px;
  }
 .element .doubleheight {
    height: 220px;
  }
 .element .doubleheight .element-content {
   position: relative;
 }
 .element .fullheight {
    height: 350px;
 }
 .element .no-padding {
   padding: 0px !important;
 }
 /**** Shapes ****/
 .play-button {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-left: 100px solid #94111e;
   border-top: 60px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

What I'm looking for is this:

[image]

I could just give it a margin top/left to center it, but the `.element` container is of variable height and width.

Anyone know how to achieve this? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the generated CSS?

Comment: Sure @ZoltanToth :-) Just updated my question with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the `.element-content` be `position:relative` and then

add

```
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:-60px;
   margin-left:-50px;
```

to the `.play-button`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jKs6F/

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `.play-button` class as follows:

```
.play-button {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-left: 100px solid #94111e;
   border-top: 60px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

   margin-left: -50px;  /* half border-left value */
   margin-top: -60px; /* border-top value */
   position: relative; left: 50%; top: 50%;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6P78/)